# Why does this series converge to two different values depending on how I construct the partial sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Suppose $a_{mn}$ is defined to be $1$ when $m=n$, $-(2^n-1)/2^n$ when $n=m+1$, and $0$ for any other values $m$ and $n$. Show that
>   $$
> \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}=\frac{1}{2}
> $$
>   but
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}=\frac{3}{2}
> $$

In my attempt to answer this question, I turned the infinite series into a finite series and then evaluated its limit after obtaining an expression for the finite series. However, in doing so, I noticed that it can be shown that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}
$$
Which clearly is incorrect. The attempt I made to arrive at this conclusion involved expressing the infinite series as follows
$$
\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^p\sum_{n=1}^{p+1}a_{mn}
$$
Which evaluates to $1/2$, but when I redid the attempt by instead expressing the infinite series as
$$
\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{p+1}\sum_{n=1}^p a_{mn}
$$
it evaluates to $3/2$. I haven't so far been able to reason why this is the case. Any explanation as to why this happens is much appreciated. Also, if anyone would be so kind as to help me get started on this question properly, I would be very thankful.

Comment: When you do either summation first, you end up with the difference of two diverging series, i.e. a conditionally convergent series. Conditionally convergent series can converge to any real number by rearranging the order in which you add up the terms. This is the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: The first sum is $\lim_{p\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^{p+1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{mn} . $There is no reason why this should equal $\lim_{p\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^{p+1}\sum_{n=1}^pa_{mn}.$